# How to use a formatted date like a real date field

Tags: javascript, php, html, json, date

I use a legacy software that manage dates formatted as a string, I want to be able to use it like a real Date.

from

Example: Jan 1, 2015

to

datefield = 2015-01-01

Thank you

Comment: So have you looked at any of PHP's functions for manipulating dates or DateTime objects?

Comment: Or classes @MarkBaker

Comment: Do you want to just parse it's string value to something and do a new Date(parsedValues)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

cazares, you can try using the createFromFormat method from the DateTime class, take a look at this link:

http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php

In your case you can use it like this:

```
$dateObj = DateTime::createFromFormat("M j, Y", "Jan 1, 2015");
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: You can also do `$d = new DateTime($myStringDate);`

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will help you.

http://plnkr.co/edit/aLjEGzrD9rPRCHh2KqC6?p=preview

Check the console.

```
var dateString = 'Jan 1, 2015';

var arr = dateString.split(/[ ,]/g);
arr = ["Jan", "1", "", "2015"];
arr.splice(2,1);
console.log(arr[0]);

var monthArr = ['Jan', 'Feb', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'Aug', 'Sept', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'];
var index = monthArr.indexOf(arr[0]);
var newDate = new Date(arr[2],index,arr[1]);

var result = newDate.getFullYear()+'-'+(newDate.getMonth()+1)+'-'+newDate.getDate();

console.log(result)
```

//will print "2015-1-1"

Answer (score 0):

This is some ugly ass code, but it should work. Used a switch-case to change the month from string to actual date. I am still not sure if you want the date as a date-object in javascript or as a new string on the new format. However, it should not be a big problem to change once the code is implemented. Happy coding.

```js
var somedate = "Dec 1, 2015";
console.log(convert(somedate));

function convert(theString) {

  var res = theString.split(/,| /);
  var month = res[0];
  var day = res[1];
  var year = 0;
  if (res[2].length == 4) {
    year = res[2]
  } else {
    year = res[3];
  }

  var convMonth = monthConverter(month);
  var newDate = year + "-" + convMonth + "-" + day;

  return newDate;
}

function monthConverter(converterMonth) {
  switch (converterMonth) {
    case 'Jan':
      converterMonth = 1
      break;
    case 'Feb':
      converterMonth = 2
      break;
    case 'Mar':
      converterMonth = 3
      break;
    case 'Apr':
      converterMonth = 4
      break;
    case 'May':
      converterMonth = 5
      break;
    case 'Jun':
      converterMonth = 6
      break;
    case 'Jul':
      converterMonth = 7
      break;
    case 'Aug':
      converterMonth = 8
      break;
    case 'Sep':
      converterMonth = 9
      break;
    case 'Oct':
      converterMonth = 10
      break;
    case 'Nov':
      converterMonth = 11
      break;
    case 'Dec':
      converterMonth = 12
      break;
    default:
      converterMonth = 1
      break;
  }

  return converterMonth;
}
```